# How to multiple runs in apify?

Tags: json, apify

I want to scraps the Instagram post comments via [Instagram Comment Scraper.](https://apify.com/zuzka/instagram-comment-scraper)

but Instagram comment limit is 24 and that scraps 24 comments per one run.
that I should using multiple runs for solve this.

for example I want to scrap a post contains 240 comments that should run 10 time and save data in one dataset.

anyone can help me for this? what should I do? what should be my JSON input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldnt help like you describe as Instagram always shows the first comments first, so you would just get 10x the same comments.
If you need more and want to stick with Apify try this actor: https://apify.com/jaroslavhejlek/instagram-scraper - it is more complex but once you set it, it will scrape many more comments than the one you mention. Important things: For scraping more comments you need use cookies (how to is described in the readme) - it is much better to use a dummy account for it and not your real one which you want to keep. Also you need to set proxies for automatic and NOT use residentials for it.
Including pic of what you should add to the input: [input of the actor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U84VR.png)